# seedstack Explicit bindings are required and MYOBJECT is not explicitly bound

Tags: java, seedstack

I am a newbe using seedstack the "Clean Java development" framework (seedstack.org).
My first action here was to create a singleton object and call it in my rest service. But seedstack throws an error...

```
/*** MY SINGLETON ***/
package com.opel.application.partmapping.domain.shared;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class AppSingleton {
private String aSingleStr = "Xxxxxxx Yyyyy @ Zzzz" ;
       public String getASingleStr() {
             this.aSingleStr = this.aSingleStr + "x" ;
             return this.aSingleStr;
       }
}
```

/*** MY REST SERVICE ***/
    package com.opel.application.partmapping.interfaces.rest;

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import org.seedstack.seed.Application;
import org.seedstack.seed.Configuration;
import org.seedstack.seed.Logging;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import com.opel.application.partmapping.domain.shared.AppConfig;
import com.opel.application.partmapping.domain.shared.AppSingleton;


@Path("hello")
public class HelloResource {

    @Inject
    private Application application;

    @Inject
    private AppSingleton theAppSingle;

       @Logging
       private Logger logger;

       @Configuration
       private AppConfig theAppConfig;

    @GET
    @Path("hello1")
    public String hello1() {
       logger.info("Hello Xxxxxxx... in hello1() ");
        return "The author of this tool is ..."  ;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("hello2")
    public String hello2() {
        return "The author of this tool is ..." + theAppConfig.getTheAuthor();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("hello3")
    public String hello3() {
       AppConfig myConfig = application.getConfiguration().get(AppConfig.class);

        return "The author of this tool is ..." + myConfig.getTheAuthor();
    }    

    @GET
    @Path("hello4")
    public String hello4() {

        return "The singleton ..." + theAppSingle.getASingleStr();
    }
}
```

**Seedstack is throwing the ERROR message:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.seedstack:seedstack-maven-plugin:2.7.1:watch (default-cli) on project PartMapper: An exception occurred while executing SeedStack application: [CORE] Unexpected exception: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1) Explicit bindings are required and com.opel.application.partmapping.domain.shared.AppSingleton is not explicitly bound.
[ERROR]   while locating com.opel.application.partmapping.domain.shared.AppSingleton
[ERROR]     for field at com.opel.application.partmapping.interfaces.rest.HelloResource.theAppSingle(HelloResource.java:22)
[ERROR]   at org.seedstack.seed.rest.internal.RestModule.configure(RestModule.java:41) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> io.nuun.kernel.core.internal.injection.KernelGuiceModuleInternal -> org.seedstack.seed.rest.internal.RestPlugin$1 -> org.seedstack.seed.rest.internal.RestModule)
```

**I do not know what bindings are required and how and where to add them.
Can anyone help me to solve that issue?**

Answer (score 1):

This errors tells you that, when trying to inject an `AppSingleton` instance, the injector doesn't know how. The injector terminology for "how to inject something" is "a binding". Think of it as a rule of injection.

In your case, you can this error because the [`@Singleton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Singleton.html) annotation is not enough to create a binding: it just specifies the scope of the potential binding.

SeedStack does a lot of bindings for you by scanning the classpath and finding classes of interest (for instance [`@Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html)-annotated classes are JAX-RS resources automatically bound by the REST module). In your case, you want to create an arbitrary binding, so you have to use the [`@Bind`](http://seedstack.org/javadoc/org/seedstack/seed/Bind.html) annotation:

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import org.seedstack.seed.Bind;

@Singleton
@Bind
public class AppSingleton {
    private String aSingleStr = "Xxxxxxx Yyyy @ Zzzz" ;

    public String getASingleStr() {
        this.aSingleStr = this.aSingleStr + "x" ;
        return this.aSingleStr;
    }
}
```

Note that I kept the [`@Singleton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Singleton.html) annotation since you wanted a singleton in the first place. If you omit it, you will only have a binding without scope, meaning that everytime an instance must be injected, a new one will be created (good for statelessness).